# Matrix multiplication and nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, nilpotence

Given that you have an $n\times n$-matrix called $A$ with the property that $A^k = 0$. Prove that $A^n = 0$.

Have heard about eigenvalues and null space as ways for the proof. The thing is that I can't wrap my head around how to use null space and we haven't learned about eigenvalues yet. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: What is $k$ in this? I am assuming that $k >n$. Hint: think in terms of minimal polynomial.

Comment: Or characteristic polynomial: $A^k=0$ (I'm assuming, for some integer $k>0$) hence $A$ has only the eigenvalue $0$. Therefore, the characteristic polynomial is $X^n$ and $A^n=0$ per [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).